# Don't Animate X If Animation X Already Running (inside keyup)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, keyup

The way it's currently written causes the hide to fire over and over if msg.d starts returning 'false' from 'true' until enough time has passed for the animation to stop.

Is there an isHiding or something?

Thanks in advance!

```
if(msg.d == "true") {
    if(!$("#addContactEmailError").is(":visible")) {
         $("#addContactEmailError").show('bounce');
    }
    $("#addContactSubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
}
else {
    if($("#addContactEmailError").is(":visible")) {
         $("#addContactEmailError").hide('slide', { direction: "up" });
    }
    $("#addContactSubmitButton").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

**Edit 1**

This is all in a keyup handler.

**Edit 2**

Using animated only fires the animation when it's completed.  If msg.d changes, but the now incorrect animation isn't finished, the correct animation won't fire.

**Lame Solution**

I used a global boolean to keep track of the state.  I hate doing that.  Putting up a bounty for a better solution when I can.  Thanks to all!

**Canceled Bounty**

Sorry guys, didn't realize I had to buy with my own rep. :(

Comment: Have you tried `$(elem).is(':animated')`?

Comment: Side note, cache your selectors. Constantly querying the DOM even by ID is slow.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion!  This should probably speed up my gridview with cross checking checkboxes all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `stop` an animation, mid animation, and make it move from that `stop`ped css state to another, use , most importantly, `stop(true, false)`.

Bottom line: `stop(true,false)` "magically" stops the animation in its' tracks but considers the css to be set to whatever the stopped animation's css parameters were, so you can continue from that point without trying to guess or figure out how you should animate from the `stop`ped point.

In other words, if you set the css through `animate`, but you `stop`ped it, the element animated will remain at whatever css state the `stop` fired at, but the css settings that were entered in the `stop`ped animation will be the current css settings until changed.

That's key.  You don't have to guess where the `stop` left the css state.  You can continue back as if your animation fully completed.

This is a demonstration of the basics of this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/65/

---

Ripped off the base animation from here: [Jquery layered animation slide out from under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638034/jquery-layered-animation-slide-out-from-under)

---

**Postscript**

Because of the ease of `animate`, `absolute` positioning within `relative` positioning, `offset`, and `stop(true,false)`, it's rare that I use any of the built in animations.  They're too clunky and don't know what you really need.  They're great for the most basic animations, but if you want to make your page shine, those concepts above (which are very easy I might add), need to be harnessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's currently being animated using the animated selector.

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: What if it's in the process of showing?  It's for a keyup.  Probably should've added that important fact :/.

Answer (score 1):

As above suggest use the ":animated" seclector

```
if(msg.d == "true") {
    var contact = $("#addContactEmailError");

    if(!contact.is(":visible") && !contact.is(":animated")) {
         contact.show('bounce');
    }
    $("#addContactSubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
}
else {
    if(contact.is(":visible") && !contact.is(":animated")) {
         contact.hide('slide', { direction: "up" });
    }
    $("#addContactSubmitButton").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: it trips over itself.  if it's !animated, but msg.d's subsequently changed, it won't fire the animation

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy apologies for late reply could you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) as a test case?

Comment: sure, might take awhile.  need to substitute the ajax etc.  tia

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `.stop().hide(` and `.stop.show(` wherever you use `hide` and `show`.