# jQuery call CSS3 version of stop(true,false) and animate from event?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Can anyone show me how to use CSS3 to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906254/1382306)?

http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/65/

I've been trying to figure out how to call CSS3 transitions via events and stopping transitions like jQuery's `stop(true, false)` for months.

```
<div id="outer"></div>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

```
var under = true;
$("#outer").bind({
    click : function() {
        if(under){
            $("#inner").stop(true, false).animate( {
                left: 50
            }, 500);
        }
        else{
            $("#inner").stop(true, false).animate( {
                left: -50
            }, 500);    
        }
        under = !under;
    }
});
```

Comment: (offtopic) this code simplified (http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/76/)

Comment: @roXon I prefer not using the ternary because I have tons of animations firing.  The less thinking js does, the better in my case, but thank-you.

Comment: believe me that one day you become friend with ternary, it will be MORE readable than an if else in 12 lines of code, specially if you need to tackle wit tons of animations. Than may be you'll start to program more oriented also, and creating reusable animation functions.

Comment: Any way. how you plan to register a click using pure css ?

Comment: @roXon i loooooove ternary, but i don't understand that last condescension.

Comment: @roXon have no idea.  that's why i'm asking.

Comment: The last "`condescension`" is a simple Boolean toggle. will togge to true if false and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/81 (note that I only included `-webkit` for convenience).

The CSS 2D transform `translate` can be used to move an element along the X/Y axis.  This, with a combination of CSS3 transitions, allows for a similar animation.

If you wanted to do this purely with CSS, then you would have to make the red box a `<label>` for checkbox element and then have a selector like `:checked + .slideout` that would include the translate rule.

There is no way to stop CSS transitions during animation; only once the animation is complete (by removing the rule).

Comment: cause your example is exactly what the OP needs, but as far we need to register a click event using JS I think that the `.toggleClass()` i used is simplifying your demo (and the OP needs) a LOT :)

Comment: @ExplosionPills: It's because roXon simplified your script.

Comment: @roXon I'm all for simplifying the script .. I was just building off of what the OP already had since it was there after all.  It's plausible that he wants to do more than just toggle the class on click as well.

Comment: @ExplosionPills you're totally right. in that case you could suggest a 2-function method that will imply the use of `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` :)

Comment: @roXon why is it what I need if it doesn't animate the way it does in my original fiddle?  it doesn't work

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy are you sure? jave you tried this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/78/

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy I wasn't going for an *exact* animation, I was just trying to illustrate the concept.  If you're really going to be that picky, then here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/81/

Comment: @roXon are you?  yours doesn't work in my chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m

Comment: @ExplosionPills please link to new fiddle in answer so i can +1

Comment: @ExplosionPills if you can confirm that `addClassing`ing is smoother than `css`ing, i'll give check

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy I think that you're really misunderstanding here .. my answer is more or less identical to dunli's, I just expanded on the answer by telling you about `translate` and explaining that you can't stop animations.  I doubt either one is noticeably smoother, but since changing the class and using transitions allows the browser to do the animation on its own I would say it is inherently better than using user-defined JavaScript.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I appreciate it!  I need smoother because I'm doing a TON of animations on my site.  Are there docs that can confirm changing the class is smoother?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy  I doubt it.  Since it's probably situational you may just want to do your own tests to compare .. it's not difficult to switch between either implementation.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/82/ this one works? just added the missing -browser-specifics about we're talking all the time

Comment: @roXon no.  ex's answer does

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy you mean my answer does not work at all? Or was just the problem for you to adjust the px ?

Comment: @roXon no, i meant what i said.  i have no problem adjusting any `px`.  i could tell you how if you like.

Comment: @ExplosionPills yep, you're right.  using the class is faster.  just tried to mix the two, and the `removeClass`-`addClass` combo happens before `css` lol.  ty very much!

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dYYZP/77/) what you want to do?

I just added below code to your `#inner`'s css:

```
transition:left .5s;
-moz-transition:left .5s;
-webkit-transition:left .5s;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: genius!  i can't believe it's that easy!  the animation is completely css3?

Comment: can't wait the day we'll not have to use -browser-specifics.