# setTimeout only works when passed a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

So I am trying to implement a smooth scroll function using vanilla javascript. I found a solution here on stack overflow and made it work for my situation. I'm confused because the solution I have now passes a string to setTimeout. From what I've read it's preferable to pass a function instead. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work any other way.

---

The little part of the code that calls setTimeout looks like this:

```
setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
```

I've tried it like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, leapY)}, timer * speed);
```

and instead of a smooth scroll it jumps to the top of the page.

---

**Is there something I'm missing when it comes to passing anonymous functions to setTimeout?**

---

The whole smooth scroll code block looks like this:

```
toTopButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var startY = window.pageYOffset;
  var stopY = 0;
  if (startY < 100) {
    scrollTo(0, stopY);
  }

  var speed = Math.round(startY / 100);
  if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;

  var step = Math.round(startY / 25);
  var leapY = startY - step;
  var timer = 0;
  for (var i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
    leapY -= step;
    if (leapY < stopY) {
      leapY = stopY
    };
    timer++;
  }
});
```

Quick explanation:

- It's triggered when a 'toTop' button is clicked.
- If yOffset < 100 it jumps to top. Otherwise speed is determined by distance from top and maxes out at 20.
- A for loop negatively increments a variable equal to the start position by a predetermined leap value until start position equals 0.
- Window is scrolled over time using setTimeout, the leap value, and an incremented timer.

Thank you for any insight you can offer!

Comment: Are you missing `}` when you call it via `anonymous function`? Or is it copy/paste mistake. Also see if you have any console errors in the browser..

Comment: theres no difference between passing an anonymous function vs passing a named function both will result in the same execution

Comment: you should simplify your code to test instead of let us to understand your logic and test

Comment: I see you are using straight javascript, but you can do this easily using jQuery and other libraries. An example can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935318/smooth-scroll-to-top

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks for pointing that out. That was a mistake when copying my code over. Definitely an error without that bracket but nothing when it's there.

Comment: The duplicate has more details, but in short: `setTimeout((function (leapY) { return function () { window.scrollTo(0, leapY); }; })(leapY), timer * speed);` should fix the problem. You might want to look into a different way, though, with a single timer running at a time (that starts another timer if the destination hasn’t been reached).

Comment: @Ryan thank you. That way does work. But also raises a lot more questions for me. Many things that are still a mystery to me with javascript, but I appreciate the help!