# Adding smooth animation to scrollTo button function using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I'm new to this please don't judge me I looked around on the net and every video or suggestion seems over complicated as I managed my button to go to the top, I'm just missing the smooth animation. What am I missing form the below code?

```
 const myBtn = document.querySelector("#myBtn");
 myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [smooth scroll to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935318/smooth-scroll-to-top)

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy, like I am then you can use this [jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll) to get smooth scrolling to your link

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scrollIntoView()`?

It can use smooth behavior.

ref: [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugins just use

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```