# Javascript back to top without adding # to the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I am a JavaScript rookie. Using a free template code for building a web page. I have a perfectly working back to top snippet but the problem is, it is adding "#" to the URL when i click on it. And when i click browser back button i had to click twice as it is removing the hash on first click and then click again to go to previous page, which is pretty annoying. Though there are tons of jQuery examples to achieve this i don't want to add jQuery and use just the JavaScript i have. Here is the code. Is there any way to remove "#" from the URL when i click the scroll to top anchor?. I tried changing the anchor tag to button as well but i could not manage to get it work. Pleas help.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>
```

JS

```
(function () {
    /**
       * Easy selector helper function
       */
      const select = (el, all = false) => {
        el = el.trim()
        if (all) {
          return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
        } else {
          return document.querySelector(el)
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * Easy event listener function
       */
      const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
        let selectEl = select(el, all)
        if (selectEl) {
          if (all) {
            selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
          } else {
            selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
          }
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * Easy on scroll event listener 
       */
      const onscroll = (el, listener) => {
        el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
      }
           
    
      /**
       * Back to top button
       */
      let backtotop = select('.back-to-top')
      if (backtotop) {
        const toggleBacktotop = () => {
          if (window.scrollY > 100) {
            backtotop.classList.add('active')
          } else {
            backtotop.classList.remove('active')
          }
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', toggleBacktotop)
        onscroll(document, toggleBacktotop)
      }
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent default event handling in an onclick method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method)

Comment: you can try this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926067/7162602

Comment: Might this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: @ evolutionxbox too good for me to understand it as said I am a rookie.

Comment: Arman and insyri both of your js may work but not without fiddling my show hide visibility of the anchor. Thanks for the answers though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the `#` being added to the url you can use `preventDefault` to prevent the default anchor link behaviour:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>


<a href="#">Back to Top</a>
```

or use `window.scroll` for native smooth scrolling behaviour (but be wary of the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollTo))

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>


<a href="#">Back to Top</a>
```

Comment: FYI: Smooth scroll can also be added via CSS: `html:focus-within { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer to your question ?

Make an `onClick` function with this sample:

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to scroll to the top:

```
backtotop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollTo({top: 0});
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to prevent the default behavior.

```js
document.querySelector(".back-to-top").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: tried just stooped the scroll behavior all together.

Answer (score 0):

I listen for hashtags with two listeners: one for within page navigation and one for when a page loads (in the event another page links to a hashed target on a different page).

The hashchange listener removes the hash for within page navigation, and the load listener removes the hash when pages switch.

These listeners remove the hash when "#" is used to scroll or jump to the top of a page. These listeners also remove all other hash tags as well.

The listeners can be adapted to retain parameters after the hash, if needed or desired.

I relied on this discussion:  [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

```js
function removeLocationHash() {
    window.history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, ''));
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    removeLocationHash();
});
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    removeLocationHash();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript:void(0) instead of #

It will work.

Comment: sorry it did not work. I have already tried adding javascript:; earlier none of them worked.